# Android override the hosts file

Tags: android, ssl, android-emulator, adb

#### Question

I want to call my secure website, which is using a self-signed certificate, and is running on my development machine, from my emulator that is running on the same machine

#### context

I create a self-signed certificate, and installed on my development machine, and edited the hosts file to link the localhost to my domail. So:
https://mydomain:8080 works perfectly on my development machine.

I installed the same certificate on my emulator, so:
https://10.0.2.2:8080 works but there emulator cannot verify the certificate because I am calling 10.0.2.2 while the certificate is issued for `mydomain`

**The solutoin** is to link the 10.0.2.2 to my `mydomain` on the hosts file

**The problem** is that I am not able to override (edit) the hosts file on the emulator, the error message states that the file is "read-only"

#### My attempts

It is being a long time and I am trying, I almost tried everything thing I could found, but no success, to list some:

**First**

adb shell 
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
chmod 777 /system

The I get the same error message

**Second**
I run the emulator from adb command, with writable permission, but the same error happened

**Third**

I tried to root the emulator so I can use apps, such as Hosts Editor, but after so many trial and errors, I am not able to root the emulator

Well, I tried many, I hope you guys can give me some insights

#### Update

According to the [aastefanov's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52443/the-command-adb-root-works-but-adb-remount-results-in-operation-not-permit), maybe the `system/` folder is still not allowed to have write access on it

Comment: 1) you've already remounted `/system` in `rw`, no need to `chmod 777 /system`; 2) `adb shell` runs on emulator with root privileges, no need to root the emulator; 3) note, that once you've exited a shell session you should remount `/system` again next time.

Comment: @Onik the thing is without the `chmod` I was getting error `permission denied`, so a different message that `read only`, and with adb shell running, I couldn't push the file (as I already said). Finally, I do remount `/system` at the end, but that doesn't affect my current problem, do you agree please?

Comment: Tried pushing to `data/local/tmp` or sdcard, then `adb shell`, then remounting, then copying from where you pushed it into to `/system`?

Comment: @Onik I didn't tried that, but will do tomorrow, kindly what's the adb command to copy the file from `tmp` to `system/etc`?

Comment: `cp` or `mv` if those binaries are in `/system/bin`...

Comment: @Onik will update you tomorrow, many thx

Comment: @Onik I got the same annoying "read only file system" error message

Comment: @Onik as you can read, I found a work around, but still actively looking for a permanent solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

The solution is to modify the hosts file from the shell script, without overtiring it.

**Move technical stuff**

1. adb root
2. adb shell
3. su //to get the root access
4. whoami // just to be sure we are the root user now

//now we are root but we cannot modify the hosts file because it is just on read-only state

5. mount -o rw,remount /system //to make it writable (you can be more specific and apply it to just system/etc folder)
6. echo "10.0.2.2 williamromadomain" >> /system/etc/hosts

#### This is just a work around, because I have to do that every time I run the simulator

Comment: @Onik no I don't creat a new one

Comment: Did u ever tried to use mount -o remount with a custom path instead of current pathmounts? I doubt so much that you can apply to /system/etc ...